# sending menu items / choices / hyperlink or anchor text for a menu like display in twilio whatsapp api

Tags: api, twilio, whatsapp

[image]

A user should be able to tap on the link so that another response comes in the chat rather than typing 1 or 2 etc. and sending it as a response.

for ex.
Are you satisfied with our info.

- Menu item 1 : [Yes](http://Yes)
- Menu item 2 : [No](http://No)

The user can tap from the above menu choices instead of typing 1 or 2.
These menu options come as blue colored links in a stacked form one below the other

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently the [Twilio API for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api) doesn't support setting quick reply buttons like you describe.

We do endeavour to add useful features for the WhatsApp API though, so do watch the [Twilio Changelog for messaging](https://www.twilio.com/changelog?product=programmable-messaging) to see when that feature is added.

Comment: thanks a lot sir for the info. also for hyperlinks can a box be shown which comes similar to quick reply?

Comment: They look like this: https://www.tyntec.com/sites/default/files/2020-05/image_wa_conversation_rounded_borders_interactive_buttons_quick_reply_1-1-1_message_03_0.35x.png.

Comment: yeah exactly, thanks for the link. how can this be achieved for hyperlinks or menu based choices?

Comment: As I said, currently the Twilio API for WhatsApp does not support that feature yet.